# Removed EventListener still fires

Tags: javascript

I have an event like so:

```
var CountDemKeys;
document.body.addEventListener('keypress', function() { 
  CountDemKeys++;
  if (CountDemKeys % 10 === 0) {
    alert("WOO HOO!");
  }
});
```

and in a separate function:

```
RemoveShizzle = function() {
  document.body.removeEventListener('keypress');
};
```

But the event still fires :(

**note:** I've also tried setting the event to `null`: `document.body.addEventListener('keypress', null);`

```
document.body.addEventListener('keypress', null);
```

no joy...

Comment: you'll have to resupply the handler function as the second argument. [See](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.removeEventListener)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.removeEventListener

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to pass the same function as the second argument to `removeEventListener`.

There could be other listeners attached to `'keypress'` to the body element.

Thus, without supplying the original function, `removeEventListener` does not know which listener to remove.

```
var CountDemKeys;
var listener = function() { 
  CountDemKeys++;
  if (CountDemKeys % 10 === 0) {
    alert("WOO HOO!");
  }
};
document.body.addEventListener('keypress', listener);

RemoveShizzle = function() {
  document.body.removeEventListener('keypress', listener);
};
```

Comment: Ah ok, thanks - (goes back to the drawing board). Unless there's a way to unbind an anonymous function?

Comment: There is no way to reaccess an anonymous function without assigning it to a variable or a property of an object.

Answer (score 0):

You're most probably missing the second argument of [**removeEventListener**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.removeEventListener).

Also please note that for MSIE support, you would need to use [**attachEvent**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener#Compatibility)